# Login Access 2007 with ODBC linked table from Oracle

Tags: oracle, ms-access, odbc, ms-access-2007

I'm migration Access 2003 to 2007. There are a lot of linked table from Oracle. I create a ODBC point to Oracle instance, then in Access I link all table through ODBC. I use this code login, so the "Oracle ODBC Driver Connect" dialog box would not popup to ask password:

```
  strConnect = "ODBC;DATABASE=" & strFCPD & ";DSN=PBRIS;UID=xxxxx;PWD=xxxxx"
  Dim wsp As Workspace
  Set wsp = DBEngine.CreateWorkspace("xxx", "xxx", "xxx", dbUseODBC)
  Set dbs = OpenDatabase("", False, True, strConnect)   ' connect via regular ODBC
  dbs.Close
```

It works fine in 2003 but not in 2007. What's wrong here? What should I do?

Comment: What error do you get in A2007?

Answer (score 0):

Does Access 2007 use a different ODBC driver than Access 2003?  If so you'll need to create a new DSN which uses the Access 2007 driver.  It looks like the existing DSN is named "PBRIS".  Go into the ODBC Administrator and create a new DSN using the System DSN tab of the administrator tool, and specify the Access 2007 driver instead of the Access 2003 driver.  You'll probably want to name it differently - perhaps something like "PBRIS2007".  You'll need to change your code which builds the connect string to specify the new data source name.

I hope this helps.

Comment: The ODBC driver is for Oracle, and ODBC is something that Access is agnostic about. So there can't be a difference with the ODBC driver between Access versions.